# How to create a bean in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created a bean class in action script using flash builder getters and setters method.
the class is :`

```
package default{

public class AccountBean
{
    private var _username:String;
    private var _email:String;

    public function get username():String {
        return _username;
    }

    public function set username(value:String):void {
        _username = value;
    }
    public function get email():String {
        return _email;
    }

    public function set email(value:String):void {
        _email = value;
    }


    public function AccountBean() {
    }
}
}
```

How to use set and get methods for this, is this creation of class is correct or not? please help

Comment: the class is technically correct...  what exactly is your question?  to use the getter/setter methods you act just like they're properties...  var bean:AccountBean = new AccountBean();  bean.email = "user@example.com";  trace(bean.email);

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct!

```
     var bean:AccountBean = new AccountBean();

     //using the setters
     bean.username = "Whatever";
     bean.email = "bean@whatever.com";

     //using the getters
     trace( bean.username , bean.email ); // Whatever bean@whatever.com
```